# Show that there is some subsequence with $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}) >0.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure, limsup-and-liminf

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let $A_n$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0, 1]$ and suppose that $\limsup _{n→∞} \mu(A_n) = 1$. Show that there is some subsequence with $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}) >0.$ [Hint: Arrange for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1−\mu(A_{n_k}))<1$.]

I have a kind of "proof" for that but :

1- Is my proof correct?

2- If so, what is the use of the hint that the book has given?

My attempt : For $A_n$ a sequence of Lebesgue measurable set we have $\limsup _{n→∞} \mu(A_n)  \le \mu( \limsup _{n→∞} A_n)$, so by $\limsup _{n→∞} \mu(A_n) = 1$ we have $\mu( \limsup _{n→∞} A_n) \ge 1$ and because all $A_n \subset [0,1]$ so $\mu( \limsup _{n→∞} A_n) = 1$ which means the measure of all elements of $[0,1]$ that belongs to infinitely many $A_n\subset [0,1]$ is 1, and that infinitely many sets is a subsequence $A_n$ and $\mu(\cap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n_k}) = 1 >0.$

Comment: Are you sure that you can make  $\mu \left( \cap _{k=1}^{\infty}A_{n_k}\right)=1$ or just arbitrarily close to $1$ for different choices of subsequences? It could be that $\mu(A_n)<1$ for every $n$, and so when you chose a definite subsequence and take the intersection the measure is necessarily less than $1$

Comment: Check here an answer that I posted a few years ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768073/subsequence-construction-for-lebesgue-inequality/2768198#2768198. You last argument is not correct, the fact that $\mu(\limsup A_n)=1$ does not immediately imply that if you pick an arbitrary subsequence of sets $A_{n_k}$ then $\mu(\cap A_{n_k})=1$.

Comment: @MiloMoses, each element of $\limsup _{n→∞} A_n$ belongs to each set $A_{n_k}$ that each is chosen from $\limsup _{n→∞} A_n$ so the measure of intersection is 1 since $\limsup _{n→∞} A_n=1$

Comment: I don't understand. If the $A_n$ are the intervals $[0, 1-\frac{1}{n}]$, then the limsup is surely $1$ but since any subsequence will contain at least some value $A_n$ for a finite $n$, then the measure of the intersection can be at most $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Choosing a subsequence where the smallest value of $A_n$ included is arbitrarily large, we can make the measure of the intersection arbitrarily close to $1$ though

Comment: @dem0nakos, thanks, your answer solved my problem! :)

Comment: @MiloMoses, thanks your comment was very useful :)